# Problems with MS Access update statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

This is my code i'm trying to update table via VB forms , I don't know what the wrong with it please help me.

This is the table:

[image]

```
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; data source = |datadirectory|\Studen.accdb;")
    con.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "Update tend set StudentName='" & TextBox9.Text & "', LessonDate='" & TextBox13.Text & "', LessonTime=" & TextBox10.Text & ", Payment=" & TextBox11.Text & ", Note='" & TextBox12.Text & "' where ID=" & TextBox8.Text
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: We don't know what's wrong either, you forgot to mention what it's doing or not doing.

Comment: Step 1 is probably parameterised queries, not discounting sql injection attack, off the top of the head guess , would be illegal values in the date and times.

Comment: In fact seeing as you haven't wrapped any of the strings in single quotes, any text field where the value is null, spaces contains a space or indeed most punctuation is going to badly wrong.

Comment: Also, IIRC dates in access shouldn't be surrounded with single quotes by in # signs: "LessonDate = #" + TextBox13.Text + "#,.........

Comment: "Update tend set StudentName = Fred Bloggs Where ID = 1" ... for instance, Unknown column name Fred is the likely error

Comment: every thing seems true ,,,,, i don't why i'm facing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is the field named NOTE. This is a reserved keyword in MS-Access and, if you want to use it, you need to encapsulate the word with square brackets

```
    Dim sql As String = "Update tend set StudentName=...., [Note]=..."
```

but this is not the only problem here. A much bigger one is the string concatenation used to build the sql command. This approach leads to possible sql injections and problems in propertly quoting the values used to prepare the statement. Strings need to be examined to duplicate single quotes, decimals need to be passed with the proper decimal point, dates need to be encapsulated in the # symbol and so on....
A better way is using a **parameterized query**

```
   Dim sql As String = "Update tend set StudentName=?, LessonDate=?, LessonTime=?, " & _
                       "Payment=?, [Note]=? where ID=?"
   Using con = New OleDbConnection(...........)
   Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
       con.Open()
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox9.Text)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Convert.ToDate(TextBox13.Text))
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox10.Text))
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox11.Text))
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", TextBox12.Text)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox8.Text))
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   End Using
   End Using
```

In a parameterized query, like the one above, you put placeholders (?) in the query text and supply the values with the Parameters collection of the command. In this way, the work to properly quote every single value is passed to the framework and db engine. They know better than you and me how to properly quote the parameters.

Note how the **AddWithValue** method infers the correct datatype to use for the parameter looking at the datatype of value passed. If your **LessonDate** field is a field with **DateTime** type then you need to convert the textbox text (a string) to a date. This could cause an exception if you don't check before trying the conversion. (Here I assume that you have something in place to ensure valid inputs). The same reasoning should be applied to the other NON text fields. **(ID, LessonTime, Payment)**